# How to reduce the request only for five friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, apprequests

I´m making an app and want to users share with only five of their friends, with apprequests just found two filters app users or non-users or send to one or all friend.
How the user  can only choose 5 friends??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using JS SDK. Try to add parameter **max_recipients: '5'** in FB.ui apprequests js function.